# IE 8 and below issue with displaying css3 styles? Using Selectivizr JS doesn't seem to work?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cakephp, less

I've developed a layout which uses li:nth child and understand IE6,7 & 8 will struggle to show these but I was advised to use 'Selectivizr' which I've done but still no luck in displaying if anyone could advise?

I'm using less and cakePHP but the styles beyond the body tag seemed to be ignored.

http://nt.rollertestingserver.co.uk

Comment: Check to make sure your doctype is correct. Also, I would advise against using CSS3 styles for anything that cannot have a reliable fallback for IE (if you're coding for IE 8 and below, which I don't know why you'd code for 7 and below.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's just a typo in the script src path. The page links to "/NT/js/selectivizr.js" but its actual path is "/js/selectivizr.js".